# Node-mysql: How to select with multiple OR in WHERE clause? How to create a query?

Tags: node-mysql

I receive such an array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5];
```

And I need to implement a query that has many `OR`s in `WHERE` clause. I take values from my array. It looks like this:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM tbl WHERE (a.bar = 1 OR a.bar = 2 OR a.bar = 3 ... and so on)
```

How may I create such a `WHERE` part in node-mysql? Or how to pass it parameters?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is fairly old, but I've had success, at least with recent versions of node-mysql using this format:

```
var titles = ['title 1', 'title 2'];
var sql = 'SELECT t.id ' +
          '  FROM topics t ' +
          ' WHERE t.title IN (?)';
var params = [titles];
```

This translates pretty nicely to:

```
SELECT t.id FROM topics t WHERE t.title IN (\'title 1\', \'title 2\')
```

Much cleaner, I think.

Answer (score 1):

simple thing to do is to use the `join()` of the array

```
 var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 var query = 'SELECT foo, bar FROM tbl WHERE (a.bar = ';
 query = query + values.join(' OR a.bar = ') + ')';
```

That will generate the query you're looking for

Comment: This is vulnerable to with SQL injection.